# Routing multiple power supplies on the same PCB

Tags: arduino, power-supply, pcb-design

I am designing a simple battery monitoring board with Arduino nano BLE to send data to an android phone. For this board, I need a +15V,-15V,+5V supply for the sensors and Arduino respectively. Do I need to add a different plane for each and every supply trace? Or can I get away with a simple 2 layered board with the bottom plane as the ground plane?
Note: I am using LT3958 IC for power regulation. The datasheet for the IC is [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3958fa.pdf). The supply is a 68V battery pack.

[image: Eagle schematic for power supply]

Comment: No, you don't need a plane for each voltage level. It is a good idea to have a ground plane, but power can be simply connected by traces.

Comment: @JiříMaier - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However that is an *answer*, which is [not what comments should be used for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). If you are going to write an answer then, please, *write an answer* :-) Comments cannot be accepted by an OP to close a topic, they can't be edited by the writer after a short 
"grace period", they can be deleted without warning & without leaving a visible trace for various reasons, and have many other deliberate limitations. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @JiříMaier thank you